# palm rejection for android canvas

Tags: android-canvas, android-touch-event

After completing an android canvas app(where the user can draw or jot), im now curious about how a finger-touch event can be disabled.Also let me know if the following line in my manifest does anything at all

```
<uses-configuration android:reqTouchScreen=["stylus"] />
```